# Model 2 way relationships to store id in user table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, associations

I'm trying to understand how I would go about storing the ID of one model record in a separate  active record table (in this case the user table) when it gets created.

Basically, I have two models. A user which `has_many :taxes` and a tax model which `belongs_to: user`. In my application a user can only have one tax record, which currently I'm achieving by storing the `user.id` in a column in the tax model, and checking in a before filter to see if the user already has already created a tax record (which checks to see if their user.id is in the table.)

```
create_table "taxes", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "income"
    t.integer  "taxes"
    .....
```

Keep in mind this is all currently in an `index` action, which is kind of pointless since a user can only have one tax record, and only view their own tax records. It should be done with the `show` action I assume.

Now here's the problem, when a user creates their single tax record, the tax model is setup like this, all interacting with the taxes active record table:

```
def store_raw_taxes
    tax = Tax.new(user_id: user.id, income: income, taxes: taxes, rrsp: rrsp)
    tax.save
end
```

In order to use `show` (and check to see if the user already has created a tax record), I want to store the `tax_id` in the actual User's table in their row. I have created a migration `AddTaxIdToUsers` which made a reference and added a column called `tax_id` to the users table.

I don't know how to store the created tax record's ID in the user table though. This is a 2 way relationship I guess, but I don't understand how in my `store_raw_taxes` function, I would also interact with the User model. I guess it would be done in a `after_save` callback?

Would I also need to add `belongs_to: tax` to the user model in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go a bit differently.

In a one-to-one relation you don't need the `belongs_to` definition, but the `has_one`

The conceptually right way to do it, in my point of view, would be:

user.rb:

```
has_one :tax
```

Then, your method would be

```
@user=User.find(..)
@user.build_tax(income: income, taxes: taxes, rrsp: rrsp)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I have two models. A user which has_many :taxes and a tax model which belongs_to: user. In my application a user can only have one tax record

If a user can only have one tax record, then you should not use `has_many :taxes` but `has_one :tax` instead. Rails will handle everything automatically.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association

Then you won't need "before filter to see if the user already has already". However is you want to ensure that user have a tax record at all times you can `validates_presence_of :tax`

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates

It is possible, if you use nested form, that you don't need `TaxesController` at all.

Also if you use nested form you will be using `accepts_nested_attributes` and therefore will not need your `store_raw_taxes` method anymore

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html